# php array code working on localhost but not working on the server

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, amazon-web-services, loops

The array is working fine on local machine and loops through the images but it fails to work on the aws server. It says "Trying to access array offset on value of type null".

```
<?php              
                   $image1 = get_field('add_image');  
                   $image2 = get_field('add_image2');  
                   $image3 = get_field('add_image3');  
                   $images = array($image1, $image2, $image3);  
                   
     
 ?>
<?php $count = 0;  ?>
<?php foreach($images as $value):  ?> 
     <img src="<?php echo esc_url($value['url']); ?>" class="d-block w-100 wrap-image-single responsive " alt="..."> </a>
<?php $count++; endforeach;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a minor issue. Here is my process of debugging the issue:

1. Please check that you are using valid names like `add_image2, add_images3` for the function `get_field`
2. Another silly mistake might be that you would be making changes in one file and seeing the results on another file.
3. Also, make sure that you have the updated code on AWS.

These are my two cents. Let me know how it goes .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try some basic debug...

1. Check that image1,2,3 all have values e.g. `var_dump($image1)`
2. Try and dump the `$images` array and see what you have. Do you in fact have the 'url' key on each sub-array?

Comment: when I dump the images I am only getting the first element of an array which is okay because I am not looping the images. images1 also shows if test it without involving the array

Comment: thanks @DazedAndConfused the image 2 and 3 where not having a variable. misspelled the input name in the wordpress plugin. I spent 4hours for this silly mistake researching

Comment: No worries. var_dump is a developer's best friend... :)